# Performance of C# Inline Statement

Tags: c#, inline, observablecollection

I'm having a Collection of a Model

```
public class MobileModelInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Catagory { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

Here I'm assigning the `MobileModelInfo` into a `ObservableCollection` via **Inline Single Execution Statement**

**Approach #1**

```
ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo> mobList = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>((new List<MobileModelInfo>(){
    new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S4", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2011" },
    new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S5", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2013" },
    new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S6", Catagory = "Ultra Smart Phone", Year = "2015" },
    new MobileModelInfo { Name = "", Catagory = "Ultra Smart Phone", Year = "2016" }
}).Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Name)).ToList());
```

Now Consider the Comman Way of Implementation

**Approach #2**

```
ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo> mobList = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>();
MobileModelInfo mobObject = new MobileModelInfo();

mobObject.Name = "S4";
mobObject.Catagory = "Smart Phone";
mobObject.Year = "2011";
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mobObject.Name))
    mobList.Add(mobObject);

mobObject = new MobileModelInfo();
mobObject.Name = "S5";
mobObject.Catagory = "Smart Phone";
mobObject.Year = "2013";
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mobObject.Name))
    mobList.Add(mobObject);

mobObject = new MobileModelInfo();
mobObject.Name = "S6";
mobObject.Catagory = "Ultra Smart Phone";
mobObject.Year = "2015";
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mobObject.Name))
    mobList.Add(mobObject);

mobObject = new MobileModelInfo();
mobObject.Name = "";
mobObject.Catagory = "Ultra Smart Phone";
mobObject.Year = "2016";
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mobObject.Name))
    mobList.Add(mobObject);
```

Out of these two approach which one gives good performance?
In my main Project I'm having a very complex Model Class Collection. So, kindly assist me to choose a best way...

> In the First Approach only one Execution should Perform since it will be expanded by the compiler but in Second Approach more than 25 (>25) Execution should Perform. So, I need to clarify which one is best approach in the Complex Data-structure.

Comment: this is not how reference types work. in the second approach you will have a list with 3 references to a single item (`Name="", Catagory="Ultra Smart Phone", Year="2016"`)

Comment: Note that if you regularly initialize with name, category and year, it would be worth creating a constructor. (Also, are you sure these should all be strings? When do you want a year which isn't an `int`? Is the name always actually a number? Perhaps the category should be an enum?)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary - Sorry I updated the Second Approach. Now assist me which one is preferable ?

Comment: I imagine that the IL code generated will be very similar. [However, if you want to know which horse is faster, then race your horses.](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @MatthewWatson - More or Less you are Correct. In the First Approach only one Execution should Perform but in Second Approach more than 25 (>25) Execution should Perform. So, I need to clarify which one is best approach in the Complex Data-structure.

Comment: I think the first approach will be the same speed as the second, since it will be expanded by the compiler to do what the second one does.

Comment: theoretically second approach is faster because its directly checking and adding. but in first approach you are filtering the list with linq and its NOT a single execution!

However in practice for 4 items you cannot measure the difference because this operation will be done in couple of microseconds. you really need to use constructors to make your code readable.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - I agree with you. But in this Scenario which one is good approach?

Comment: i prefer this. use constructor. then create items like this. `new MobileModelInfo("S4", "Smart Phone", "2011")`. you see its a lot more readable. and also i prefer to use loop and add items inside loop.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary And what if you have a complex structure with lots of optional member initialization?  Then you have to create a whole bunch of different constructors, which bloats the code for no good reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new syntax object initializers are basically just a shorthand format that is translated into the long form.  You can confirm this with a disassembler of some sort if you like.  You will find that the code is as close to identical as it can get, barring some compiler optimizations.

For instance, this code:

```
TestClass t1 = new TestClass { iVal = 1, sVal = "two" };
```

Generates the following IL (according to LINQPad):

```
IL_0001:  newobj      UserQuery+TestClass..ctor
IL_0006:  stloc.2     
IL_0007:  ldloc.2     
IL_0008:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0009:  stfld       UserQuery+TestClass.iVal
IL_000E:  ldloc.2     
IL_000F:  ldstr       "two"
IL_0014:  stfld       UserQuery+TestClass.sVal
IL_0019:  ldloc.2     
IL_001A:  stloc.0     // t1
```

Here's the other way:

```
TestClass t2 = new TestClass();
t2.iVal = 1;
t2.sVal = "two";
```

And its IL:

```
IL_001B:  newobj      UserQuery+TestClass..ctor
IL_0020:  stloc.1     // t2
IL_0021:  ldloc.1     // t2
IL_0022:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0023:  stfld       UserQuery+TestClass.iVal
IL_0028:  ldloc.1     // t2
IL_0029:  ldstr       "two"
IL_002E:  stfld       UserQuery+TestClass.sVal
```

The only difference here is that the first creates a temporary variable (`loc.2`)  to do the creation and then stores it in the named local variable (`loc.0`).  That difference disappears when you turn optimization on.

So you can use either method with virtually 0 difference in performance.  Personally I prefer the new object initializer form, just like I prefer the LINQ query syntax.  Both are just syntactic sugar for things happening in the background, but they can have large differences in the way you read the code, and in how you write it.

Incidentally, array initializers are exactly the same.  These two produce virtually identical code:

```
int[] a1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

int[] a2 = new int[3];
a2[0] = 1;
a2[1] = 2;
a2[2] = 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

The second is not "the Comman Way" (Which is a term I never heard before). It is:

- Convoluted (checking name property for null after setting it.
- The ONLY way to do it before a certain ancient .NET update enabled the new syntax.

Which pretty much is why you learned it. Old syntax. There is no significant - particularly no measurable - performance difference.

Comment: Thanks, which one you preferring for me?

Comment: Slight correction: the change wasn't in .NET, it was in C# 3 (v3). Object and collection initializers don't require framework support - you can use them while targeting .NET 2, for example. (And if you could still easily target .NET 1, I'd expect them to work there too...)

Comment: Yes, bytecode is no difference. But there likely is still a lot of courses around not having the new syntax and a lot of people just googling and never learning the language properly.

Comment: Sure - I'm just saying that you should call it what it is, a *language* change. It would also be worth repeating ieaglle's comment - the second code is currently broken, due to only creating a single instance of `MobileModelInfo`.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Sorry I updated the Second Approach. Now assist me which one is preferable ?

Comment: Why do you think they invented a new syntax? In most cases it is preferable because it is a lot more contact.

Comment: @TomTom - I agree with you. But in this Scenario which one is good approach?

Comment: The scenario of hardcoding a small number of entities? This is neither relevant (too few) nor complex. It depends on usage as programmer - I would likely use the new syntax.